# need to export predicted results of kmeans along with original IDs in r

Tags: r

I need the export the results of kmeans clustering like
I have created a kmeans$cluster: 
sample eg:

> kmeans$cluster

```
    11 12 13 14 15 16
    3  3  2   1  2 3
```

any one know how to export the results to csv
along with the original IDs(11,12,13,14,15,16) as these are the original test ids.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post a fully reproducible example? How do you create `kmeans`?

Answer (score 0):

```
write.csv("file.csv",cbind(data,kmeans(data)$cluster))
```